# GWT app deployment with compression on embedded web server

Tags: gwt, embedded, compression

I am trying to deploy a GWT client-only app on a custom web server.  I am using the GWT pre-compress linker like this in my .gwt.xml file:

`<inherits name="com.google.gwt.precompress.Precompress"/>`

`<set-configuration-property name="precompress.leave.originals" value="false" />`

`<add-linker name="xsiframe" />`

And in my html file, I load the javascript with references to nocache.js.gz:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js.gz"></script>`

The compiler generates compressed javascript files as expected. However, when I run the app, the app is requesting *.cache.js files from the web server, and not *.cache.js.gz files as I was expecting.

I am using a custom web server that does not handle compression on-the-fly, so I am wondering if there is a way to configure GWT compiler to generate code that requests *.cache.js.gz files instead of *.cache.js files?  I can't seem to find any documentation for this, but if I've missed something in the docs, I'd appreciate a pointer.

Comment: I ended up running the following command post-gwt compile, since I could not find a decent solution: find app -name \*.js -exec perl -pi -e "s/cache.js/cache.js.gz/g;" {} \; -exec gzip -f {} \;

Comment: you shouldn're replace it by default because older browsers can't handle precompressed resources. If you only support modern browsers it won't make a difference tough.

Comment: Thanks Ümit. I understand older browsers can't handle it. I wish GWT would check user agent, and then actually request .gz where possible. But do you see any issues with my approach with IE8+, FF4+, Safari 5+?

Comment: I agree there are actually two ways to do the check: client side via user agent or server side checking the HTTP header (if compression is supported). I think the mentioned browsers should all support gzip compression. But you can check it [here](http://www.vervestudios.co/projects/compression-tests/results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PrecompressLinker](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/PrecompressLinker) will generate the .gz files.
However not all browsers support precompressed resources and thus they won't be loaded by default.

You have to configure your web-server/backend server so that it check if there precompressed resources available and if the client supports compression and then rewrites the request to retrieve the *.gz files instead of the non compressed ones.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way to configure GWT compiler to generate code that requests *.cache.js.gz files instead

No.

Let's do a thought experiment. Let's say, we could get GWT to request for a gzip file from your custom server.

Who is going to unzip it? The GWT browser client? No, you would have to write your own browser. All the Java in GWT client is translated/compiled into Javascript. And Javascript on the browser cannot call the browser's host JVM to unzip it - for security reasons.

Who is going to unzip it? The server? Then your custom server has to handle it. You need to expand the capabilities of your custom server.

I am sorry, my apologies, but I wish you to think thro the data interchange between Javascript client and your custom server meticulously. Someone has to unzip the file, somewhere - I am certain it will not be the hub or router or the transmission cable/media.

I advise people, before they indulge in GWT, to acquire some proficiency in JSP/JEE programming. Using JSP to generate the javascript and HTML for the browser to display. When you have gained reasonable experience with JSP-generated content, you would tend to understand the constraints, advantages and requirements of GWT client-server. If not JSP, then at least PHP.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the poster's question. He is not asking to unzip/zip content via Javascript/GWT but how precompressed resources can be automatically loaded. Modern browsers support server-side compression.  There is a [PrecompressLinker](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/PrecompressLinker)  in GWT which generated in addition to uncompressed resources or the precompressed resources. However GWT won't fetch them automcatically because compression is only supported by modern browsers.

Comment: @BlesedGeek All modern browsers support automatically unzipping gzip encoded content transparently. There is no need to write your own browser or access the JVM.

Comment: +Joseph, you don't know what GWT is. The browser driven unzip is mapped to an external process. External processes, for security reasons, standard browsers are to reject injection of content into a page of another url:port. Therefore, the unzipping is useless for gwt.

Comment: @BlessedGeek `Content-Encoding` is the mechanism Joseph is likely referring to. For those that stumble across this question, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding